# Angular2 showing loader in router-outlet while the particular route component is being loaded

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Some of may components are getting time to load in  `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` so I am thinking of showing loader in RouterOutlet and wait component to fully load after this hiding the loader and showing the component.

how can I achieve this? Is their any built-in features to add support of loader in RouterOutLet

Answer (score 2):

You can extend to the current angular2 router-outlet directive and create your own custom outlet.

You could then handle the showing and hiding of your loader in here.

CustomRouterOutlet,ts

```
import {Directive, Attribute, ElementRef, DynamicComponentLoader} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router, RouterOutlet, ComponentInstruction} from 'angular2/router';

@Directive({
    selector: 'router-outlet'
})

export class CustomRouterOutlet extends RouterOutlet {
    private parentRouter: Router;

    constructor(_elementRef: ElementRef, _loader: DynamicComponentLoader,
                _parentRouter: Router, @Attribute('name') nameAttr: string) {
        super(_elementRef, _loader, _parentRouter, nameAttr);

        this.parentRouter = _parentRouter;

        this.parentRouter.subscribe(()=> {
            console.log('changed');
        })
    }

    activate(instruction: ComponentInstruction) {
        console.log('activate');

        return super.activate(instruction);
    }

    deactivate(instruction: ComponentInstruction) {
        console.log('deactivate');

        return super.deactivate(instruction);
    }
}
```

Import your custom outlet here where you start your

Main.ts

```
import {Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, DynamicComponentLoader, Injector, Injectable, provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {RouteConfig, RouterLink, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, Router, CanActivate, RouteParams} from 'angular2/router';
import {CustomRouterOutlet} from './shared/directive/customOutlet'

@Component({
    selector: 'Main',
    template: require('./main.html'),
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, CORE_DIRECTIVES, RouterLink, CustomRouterOutlet],
})

export class Main {

    constructor(private router: Router) {

    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for the information... Actually I created the shared service and activated the loader in extended  **router outlet**  in deactivate function and deactivate the loader in component's AfterViewInit(As suggested by Gunter)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure there is no built-in feature for this yet. I would use some global service that manages the loader (show/hide) on a fixed position (overlay or similar).

Inject the `constructor(private router:Router)` to this service and subscribe to it to get notified about route changes `router.subscribe(...)`. 
When the route changes show the loader.

Inject the service also to components added by the router and notify the service when the component is initialized (`ngOnInit()` or `ngAfterViewInit()`) to hide the loader.